# Convert json to dataframe in python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a json file (sample below). I am trying to create a Dataframe from this using python:
JSON:

```
{"data": {
        "A": [{
                "CREATION_DATE": "1482105600",
                "SOURCE_COUNT": "0"
            },
            {
                "CREATION_DATE": "1482105600",
                "SOURCE_COUNT": "0"
            } ],
         "B": [{
                "CREATION_DATE": "1487808000",
                "SOURCE_COUNT": "1048"
                },
                {
                "CREATION_DATE": "1487894400",
                "SOURCE_COUNT": "1103"
                 } ]
         }
 }
```

When I am trying to convert it into a dataframe:

My Code:

```
import json
file = 'mysample.json'
with open(file) as train_file:
    dict_train = json.load(train_file)

# converting json dataset from dictionary to dataframe
train = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict_train, orient='index')
train.reset_index(level=0, inplace=True)
```

Output:

```
    index      A                                                   B
0   data    [{'CREATION_DATE': '1482105600', 'SOURCE_COUNT...   [{'CREATION_DATE': '1487808000', 'SOURCE_COUNT...
```

Instead I am looking to convert this into a dataframe which looks like below:

```
system  CREATION_DATE   SOURCE_COUNT
A        1482105600        0
A        1482105600        0
B        1487808000        1048
B        1487894400        1103
```

How to modify my code to get to the expected output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
pd.DataFrame(dict_train['data']).stack().apply(pd.Series).reset_index(level=0, drop=True).sort_index()


  CREATION_DATE SOURCE_COUNT
A    1482105600            0
A    1482105600            0
B    1487808000         1048
B    1487894400         1103
```

Comment: Not gonna lie, this answer is much cleaner and more efficient than mine. I'd have accepted this.

Comment: agree !  best method for sure

Answer (score 2):

Here is an answer in pure python (nb. replace `dict` with `collections.OrderedDict` in python 3.5 or lower).

```
data = []
for system, values in dict_train['data'].items():
    for value in values:
        data.append(dict(system=system, **value))


df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(data)
```

output:

```
  CREATION_DATE SOURCE_COUNT system
0    1482105600            0      A
1    1482105600            0      A
2    1487808000         1048      B
3    1487894400         1103      B
```

Answer (score 2):

This code works (but it is not using json):

```
import pandas as pd

current_dict = {"data": {
        "A": [{
                "CREATION_DATE": "1482105600",
                "SOURCE_COUNT": "0"
            },
            {
                "CREATION_DATE": "1482105600",
                "SOURCE_COUNT": "0"
            } ],
         "B": [{
                "CREATION_DATE": "1487808000",
                "SOURCE_COUNT": "1048"
                },
                {
                "CREATION_DATE": "1487894400",
                "SOURCE_COUNT": "1103"
                 } ]
         }
 }


my_list=[]

#iterate over your data: system
for system in current_dict["data"]:

    #iterate over data: system > sub-system
    for sub_system in current_dict["data"][system]:

        creation_date = int(sub_system["CREATION_DATE"])
        source_count = int(sub_system["SOURCE_COUNT"])

        #add to list
        my_list.append([system,creation_date,source_count])

#convert to panda df (adding colums name)   
df = pd.DataFrame(my_list,columns=("system","creation_date","source_count"))

print df
```

give:

```
  system  creation_date  source_count
0      A     1482105600             0
1      A     1482105600             0
2      B     1487808000          1048
3      B     1487894400          1103
```

Comment: Maybe better to refer to @filippo answer which is the best (and cleanest) method !